# add checkboxes to emptyrow using vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim MyLeft As Double
Dim MyTop As Double
Dim MyHeight As Double
Dim MyWidth As Double
dim emptyRow as long

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
        MyLeft = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Left
        MyTop = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Top
        MyHeight = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Height
        MyWidth = MyHeight = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Width

  If CheckBox1.Value = True Then

    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
         With Selection
            .Caption = ""

         End With
  End If
 End Sub
```

but for some reason, the checkboxes don't add to the emptyrow each time, instead it makes checkboxes to save column/row over and over again... how do i fix this?

Comment: A Checkbox is an object that overlays the worksheet.  It cannot be "in" a cell, hence it will never make the cell not empty, to be counted by COUNTA.  You could cycle through ActiveSheet.Checkboxes to find the one with the lowest Top property, then increment from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your location is set by `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))` and `CountA` counts cell entries only. So adding Checkboxes won't cause the count to increment

One way to adjust it would be to adjust your row count by incrementing as you add shapes

`emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) +  ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count`

Other options would be

- storing the number of `Checkboxes` added in a cell, or range name.
- adding white text to the empty cell as well (to increment `CountA(Range("A:A")`)

Answer (score 1):

If all of your checkboxes are in column A except for the one to which the code is attached, you could set empty row:

```
 emptyRow = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count
```

or some variation of that (perhaps with CountA) depending on whether you want to fill every cell, or just the cells that do not contain values.

If you might have checkboxes in other areas of the worksheet, you'll probably have to cycle through each one to see what column they are in -- those would be the ones with .Left = 0; and use those in your count.